# Does PriorityQueue heapify itself if any object in the collection is mutated so that it's key(used in comparator) changes?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I just want to know if Java's `PriorityQueue` collection automatically heapifies, if any of the keys used in the comparator is mutated, or do i need to explicitly call heapify, to order the `binary tree` ?
I am experimenting with the data structure to use it in a cache like setting, where an object in the collection should be immediately moved to the head, as soon as it is referenced.

Comment: You can create a very effective cache by combining a hash map and a linked list. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002814/is-this-algorithm-implementation-lru-or-mru for an example. It's in C#, but you should be able to convert it to Java easily enough.

Answer (score 4):

The queue automatically *heapifies* on operations that mutates the queue itself, namely `offer`, `poll`, `remove` and `add`.

**If you mutate an element you have to remove and re-insert it**. The priority queue has no way of knowing that an element has been updated.

Comment: Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Glad it helped :)